# MBP TouchBar Locking Up Sporadically

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

2016 MBP w/ Touch Bar is locking up randomly.
I'll have a few programs open and I'll try to open Mission Control or open a Stack in my Dock and it will 'freeze'

During these 'freezes' it **can** still move the mouse, and I can sort of use the Touch Bar but I can't get any apps to open, I can't use Mission Control, I  pretty much can't do anything but force shutdown the computer.

Also the Busy mouse doesn't appear.

During the freezes I've tried relaunching Finder to no avail.